# Find property "invocations" with Roslyn

Tags: c#, properties, roslyn

I'm trying to build up a call graph of C# methods and properties. This essentially means that I search the project for `MethodDeclarationSyntax` and `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` nodes. I then build connections between these nodes by looking for method invocations via:

```
SyntaxNode node = ...; //Some syntax node
var methodInvocations = node.DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
//Process these method invocations
```

Is there a similar method or recommended way to find all property "invocations" as well? I believe the C# compiler breaks properties out into Getter and Setter functions on compilation.

What's the best way to detect the usage of properties with Roslyn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Roslyn model follows source, not IL and so the individual calls to the get and set methods are not represented.

In order to do this, you'll need to find all of the `MemberAccessExpression` and `IdentifierNameSyntax` nodes and call GetSymbolInfo to see if they refer to the property.

Alternatively, you should consider bumping up a level to use the workspace model and call the `FindReferences` API instead.

Comment: Have things changed? I see some public APIs dealing with non-source code (property getters/setters): http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/IMethodSymbol.cs,1630ca4680652d53,references

Comment: No, we've always had those, because sometimes you need to find those anyway.  For example, if you have a property X, you need to know that the names get_X and set_X are now invalid.  It's not the case that we *only* represent things that appear in source (we also represent implicit conversions), but in general the philosophy of following source still applies.